# how to troubleshoot: Socket.Poll returns false?

Tags: c#, .net, udp, multicast

**resolved** I've resolved the issue turning off Windows firewall

I run the same code on two different computers.

```
s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(mcastPort));
s.Bind(ipep);

// setting options
// ................
// s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddSourceMembership, option);

if (s.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Poll returned true");
} else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Poll returned false");
}
```

On one computer code works fine, so at least SOMETIMES it works.
However on another computer it doesn't work. In one case `Poll` returns true and in another case `Poll` returns false; I've used Wireshark to check that on both computers I can see datagrams on the specified connection (mcastGroup, mcastPort, sourceIp). I was thinking that probably on second computer wrong interface is used, so I replaced `new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any...` with `new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.11.12.13")...` but this doesn't help.

The only difference I can see. On the computer where program works I can see datagrams only when program is launched. On computer where program doesn't work I always see datagrams, even if application is shutdown.

The question is - how can I troubleshot the problem?

- i'm sure that there are datagrams in network because I see them in wireshark
- i'm sure that my application and wireshark use the same multicastGroup, multicastPort, sourceIp
- i'm sure that I'm using the same interface because I provide it explicitly

But `Socket.Poll` still returns false. What else should I do?

**upd** Also I noticed in sniffer that computer that doesn't work uses IGMP v2, while computer that does work uses IGMP V3. Probably feature `AddSourceMembership` is new to IGMP v3 and that's why my program doesn't work? How to force computer to use IGMP v3?

**upd** I've created another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775405/the-same-udp-multicast-addsourcemembership-code-results-in-completely-different because I think this is not c# or .net problem

Comment: Have you tried setting a larger number of microseconds, or using "-1" to wait indefinitely? See if that helps.

Comment: @romkyns this doesn't help and I have while(true) cycle outside. I now think that error is not in program, but in configurations...

Comment: @javapowered i have the same code as you, and i see the packets in wireshark, but my socket.Poll is always returning false. You got any ideas?

Comment: maybe you can show me your multicastoption? or didn´t you use the setsocketoption line?